# OneToOneField no 'username' member in django python3 or fstring or self attribute problems

Tags: django, python-3.7

Here is my code below. why am I getting an error

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Why is my f-string messing up? It says instance on OneToOneField has no 'username' member?
Here is how I call Profile--code below--signals.py file--

```
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.dispatch import receiver
    from .models import Profile

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

So in signals.py >> 'Profile.objects.create(user=instance)' Profile contains no object member...

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `__str__` itself. You likely passed a `Profile` *class* as `self`, not a `Profile` object. How exactly do you *call* this?

Comment: it is just pylint error in vscode editor